# How is the default video player in Windows 10 achieving the low CPU utilization while playing FHD videos

Tags: playback, full-hd

I am trying to understand how the default Windows 10 player (called "Films and TV") is able to play FHD (1920 x 1080 x 60fps) videos (shot with GoPro 4) and utilize only around 10% of the CPU, while other players namely VLC and GOM will utilize around 60-70% CPU.

I tried looking at GPU utilization, but even there while using the default Windows 10 player utilization is around 15% vs around 30% when using VLC and GOM.

Right now this looks like magic to me as FHD playback is taxing on the hardware and I can't figure out what is going on. I am thinking the difference will be in the decoder used, but can't find more information.

The CPU / GPU used are Core i5 5200U / Intel HD Graphics 5500

VLC Player CPU utilization:
[image: VLC Player CPU utilization]

Films and TV CPU utilization
[image: Films and TV CPU utilization]

This is the info for a sample video file.

```
General
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media / Version 1
Codec ID                                 : mp41
File size                                : 2.61 GiB
Duration                                 : 12mn 23s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 30.1 Mbps

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.2
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=30
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 12mn 23s
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 30.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 59.940 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.241
Stream size                              : 2.60 GiB (99%)
Title                                    : GoPro AVC
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 12mn 23s
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 128 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 11.4 MiB (0%)
Title                                    : GoPro AAC
```

VLC reports the following video output in: Tools -> Messages -> Module Tree -> playlist -> video output

```
window "qt4" (0x5a738fc)
vout display "direct3d" (0x5a57a34)

subpicture (0xf456b4)
spu text "freetype" (0x5a24264)
scale "yuvp" (0x5a70c1c)
scale "swscale" (0x55a1eac)
```

Comment: Probably different renderer and/or filters used with VLC/GOM. In VLC, what does `Tools -> Messages -> Module Tree -> playlist -> video output` say?

Comment: @Mulvya Added the requested info in the body of the post/question.

Comment: Do both players played 1080p? In other words, is your display 1080p and you played the movie full-screen on both tests? If you just play in a small window it is possible that F&TV runs a partial rendering.

Comment: @avnr My display is 1600 x 900 and player are running maximized, though not in full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite possible that the Windows player can make use of some HW acceleration the others can not / are not using.

Check this how to enable HW video decoding on VLC:

- https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_GPU_Decoding
- https://superuser.com/q/128478/228841

If you are using VLC 2.2.2 check this
https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=130590

**UPDATE** from the author of the question:
Adding screenshot from VLC v. 2.2.1 to compliment this answer.

VLC 2.2.1 with Hardware Acceleration enabled.
[image]

Comment: Unlikely. Even if so, H/W accel uses GPU and FTV shows half the GPU use as well.

Comment: If your gpu does HW video decoding, I don't think it would even register as high GPU usage since it is _Hardware_ Decoding.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/128478/228841

Comment: The hardware decoder is part of the GPU die, so I'm not sure how that affects my point.

Comment: Your point is that HW decoder utilization should register on the GPU graph. Which It not necessarily does if there is a DSP actually doing the processing and not a piece of software that "runs" it's code on the GPU.

Comment: Depending on how efficient the decoder is, it should still affect the temps. Compare the GPU temps. The chief discrepancy here seems to be the post-processing/renderer, not the decoding.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You can run FullHD H264 movies on a raspberry pi, thanks to hardware acceleration and you wouldn't notice a temperature change.

Comment: If you look at the first chart [here](http://www.anandtech.com/show/7007/intels-haswell-an-htpc-perspective/5) (with the default renderer), Quicksync decoding consumes more power than DXVA2. When I compare VLC playback of FHD 30fps with s/w decode vs DXVA2 using a nV card, I register a 5% increase in GPU (30 -> 35) and 1-2 C increase in GPU temp in the latter case. That suggests that decoding doesn't account for all the discrepancy in the OP's case.

Comment: The point is: there cannot be any other real explanation for his / her original question. The Windows player uses some kind of acceleration the others are not. This also lines up with other search results related to that subject: one article praising the Windows player as less battery consuming, other articles speaking of high CPU utilization when using VLC. I think your energy would be more wisely invested trying to to figure out WHICH acceleration is missing in the other players than arguing that there is none.

Comment: I'm not arguing "WHICH acceleration is missing". I'm saying the discrepancy isn't explained by different decoding pipelines between the players.

Comment: Using ( or not using)  a HW decoder results in a different decoding pipeline. Sorry man I really think you're getting nowhere with this. And also I don't find it interesting discussing the existence of something obvious.

Comment: I have to agree  with Hans Meiser. GPU decoding absolutely explains this behavior.

Comment: @HansMeiser Today I downgraded VLC player to version 2.2.1 (in 2.2.2 hardware acceleration isn't working as you pointed out) and results are similar (though not as good) as the default Windows player. Therefore I believe hardware acceleration will explain the big difference in resource utilization. The minor difference probably has to do with some further optimizations.

Comment: Yeah, GPU decoding does explain the CPU %. But not the GPU %, which looks due to VLC's filters+renderer.